# Sending UDP stream Gstreamer

Tags: windows, gstreamer

How do you send a udp video stream to a port using gstreamer on windows?

I would like to send the testvideo to a specific port but nothing is being output when I check the network using wireshark. Here is what I have tried as a gstreamer pipeline.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264depay ! upsink port=3445
```

Here is the output in the command prompt terminal.

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... 
Pipeline is PREROLLING... 
Redistribute latency ... 
Pipeline is PREROLLED ... 
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ... 
New Clock: GstSystemClock
```

Wireshark shows no output on the network.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `rtph264pay` element for payloading instead of `rtph264depay`, and you need to define a targed ip address for `udpsink`. It is also good idea to add caps to `x264enc` stating it will output a `byte-stream`.

A sample pipeline I recommend is as follows. Feel free to replace `127.0.0.1` with your target.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! x264enc ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream ! h264parse ! rtph264depay ! upsink port=3445 host=127.0.0.1
```

A word on `h264parse`, in older versions of gstreamer you need this element, in the newer versions you don't need to use this one.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. How would you receive this stream then on another computer on the same network? I tried this pipeline but did not work. In the terminal it just sits and waits. No external video shows up and displays the test video. 

```
 gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=3445 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideosink 
```

Comment: I also tried `gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=3445 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink`. However the terminal just sits at `Setting pipeline to PAUSED... Pipeline is live and does not need preroll... setting pipeline to playing... new clock gstsytemclock`

Comment: The pipe seems correct to me. Is the ip address of the `udpsink` element correct? It is a bit tricky. The `host` property requires the ip of the _target_.

Comment: `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link h264parse0 to rtph264depay0`

Answer (score 0):

Before introducing advanced elements, let's start by simple consistency-check as below (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS):

Send udp stream:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=3445 host=ip_address
```

Receive udp stream (Receiving would takes few second to display):

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=3445 ! application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

If nothing display, try to remove vaapi:
`sudo apt-get remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi`

Let us know if it works (thumb-up) or doesn't work (thumb-down) !

Comment: Why removing vaapi would make it to work?

Comment: For the receiver, `gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc port=3445 ! application/x-rtp ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink sync=false` worked instead.